# How to get particular child key from firebase runtime database and set data on recyclerview android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have a DataSnapshot with all keys of Firebase runtime database. Here is my log:-

> E/MYDATA: DataSnapshot { key = Income, value = {-LgaZl_ojnqmvgpPe48D={date=2019-06-05, createdAt=2019-06-05 13:08:22, amount=333.00, caption=jjhj, from=yyyyy, time=13:08, type=ICICI Bank, updatedAt=2019-06-05 13:08:22}} }
>
> E/MYDATA: DataSnapshot { key = createdAt, value = 2019-06-05 11:06:18 }
>
> E/MYDATA: DataSnapshot { key = email, value = abc@gmail.com }

Here my LOG is = MYDATA , I try to  **key = Income** data render in Recyclerview

Here is my code :

```
  String id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(id);

    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            Log.e("MYDATA", "" + dataSnapshot);

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

and here is my database structure :-

Database image

[image]

[Look this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZKIk.png)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: please look at Image.

Comment: I saw the image, but i dont get what you're trying to do?

Comment: bro i have multiple records of Income or Expanse key , i just show this specify key Income data to show on Recycvlerview @VedprakashWagh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to fetch the records of "Expanse", change the `ref` to,

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(id).child("Expanse");
```

After changing it, add a `ValueEventListener` or `ChildEventListener` to the `ref`.

You've used `ChildEventListener`, so in the `onChildAdded` of `ChildEventListener`, you can get the data from Firebase like,

```
Expanse expanse = dataSnapshot.getValue(Expanse.class);
list.add(expanse);
```

Above code will come in `onChildAdded` of `ChildEventListener`, where `Expanse` is your POJO class in which you have getters and setters for amount, caption, date, etc.

Then you have to add this newly obtained object `expanse` in the `List`, and then notify your `RecyclerViewAdapter` that the data was changed.

Comment: Same for getting Income, but there are other ways of getting both in on shot. This is the simplest one

Comment: Yes this is simplest way to get data from firebase.

Comment: Hello @Vedprakash Wagh Why i only one element get in Recyclerview?

Comment: In your Expanse child, there is only one children. So you'll get only one children there. If you want more, add more children to Expanse in Firebase.

Comment: I add more 3 records but it display only last update

Comment: bro just look at this image in Logcat i data want to show in Recyclerview: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZKIk.png

Comment: So you get only the last item? Are you adding the data that you receive in onChildAdded in the list? Because you have to perform list.add(expanse) in OnChildAdded after you do dataSnapshot.getValue()

Comment: Yes , Last one data i get.

Comment: You're creating new Adapter every time a child is added. Remove the adapter = new IncomeAdapter() from OnChildAdded and make it execute only once. After the items are added, call adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();

Comment: Thank you sorry it's my bad mistake. its work . Thank you